# How to load table fast on phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need your opinion or solution because I'm stuck with the MySQL phpyadmin, I have two table, 1 table has 29,000 of records which loads for about 2s and the other table has 30,000 records which loads about 5 minutes, I want to know how can I improve the loading time of this 5 minute time of table 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want the whole tables completely: By better hardware; More and faster RAM, faster disks and/or buses and faster network interfaces (if the DBMS isn't on the same machine phpMyAdmin is on), maybe also faster and or more CPUs or CPUs with larger caches (though the impact of upgrading the CPUs can be very minor here)...

Comment: Before "throwing hardware at it", let's see the table definitions and some sample data and whether you are using `LOAD DATA` or something slower.

Comment: I investigated something and I freak out, my 30k records are 50gb of size but the data type is only a "LONGTEXT" with JSON values, please help because I don't have idea what's going on. thanks!

Comment: I have figured out the solution, I have a logic error on my loopings.